# PHP - File to Associative Array with 1 key and two values attached

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array, key-value

I have a text file that contains:

```
email:number1:number2    
email:number1:number2    
email:number1:number2    
email:number1:number2
```

What i need to do is store these in an associative array where the email is the key and the numbers are values.

How can i do this with PHP?

Below is my attempt so far

```
<?php

// file path 
$file = 'orderdata'; 
// open the file and get the resource handle with errors suppressed 
$handle = @fopen($file,'r'); 
// array to hold our values 
$params = array(); 
if($handle) 
{ 
// if handle is there then file was read successfully 
// as long as we aren't at the end of the file 
   while(!feof($handle)) 
   { 
       $line = fgets($handle); 
       $temp = explode(':',$line); 
       $params[$temp[0]] = $temp[1]; 
   } 
   fclose($handle); 
} 

function search_array ( array $array, $term )
{
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
        if ( stripos( $value, $term ) !== false )
            return $key;

    return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: and what you have tried till now ? show your code

Comment: @shatheesh i have edited the post with what i have tried so far :-)

Comment: what error you are facing? what's the o/p of `$params`

Comment: Im not really facing any errors, it just doesn't work. This piece of code was a first attempt which i know is so wrong. all i need is to store a text file in an associative array with 1 key and 2 values :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
// file path 
$file = 'orderdata.txt';  // REMEMBER TO MENTION THE CORRECT FILE WITH EXTENSION
// open the file and get the resource handle with errors suppressed 
$handle = @fopen($file,'r');  // DONT USE @ while at development since it will suppress errors
// array to hold our values 
$params = array(); 
if($handle) 
{ 
// if handle is there then file was read successfully 
// as long as we aren't at the end of the file 
   while(!feof($handle)) 
   { 
       $line = fgets($handle); 
       $temp = explode(':',$line); 
       $params[$temp[0]][] = $temp[1]; 
       $params[$temp[0]][] = $temp[2]; 
   } 
   fclose($handle); 
}
```

Check the `$file = 'orderdata.txt'` in your script and add appropriate extension , this will work only if the php file and the `orderdata` file are in the same path. If not, then provide an absolute path for the file and try

If the input is like this,

```
test1@example.com:1:11    
test2@example.com:2:12    
test3@example.com:3:13    
test4@example.com:4:14
```

Then the above script will output like

```
Array
(
    [test1@example.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 11    

        )

    [test2@example.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 12    

        )

    [test3@example.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 13    

        )

    [test4@example.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 14
        )

)
```